# debugging a mahout logistic regression

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am new to mahout.. And I am trying out the standard "donut" example listed here:

http://imiloainf.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/mahout-logistic-regression/

So this example works like a charm.

But when I try to implement it on my dataset (whcih is a huge dataset) it doesnt works.

The dataset is in one csv file.. everything is same except it has a lot of features (~100) and is 1TB file.

I am getting this error.

```
 bin/mahout trainlogistic  --input /path/mahout_input/complete/input.csv \
--output mahoutmodel --target default --categories 2 --predictors O1 E1 I1 \
 --types numeric --features 30 --passes 100 --rate 50
Running on hadoop, using HADOOP_HOME=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2
No HADOOP_CONF_DIR set, using /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.CsvRecordFactory.firstLine(CsvRecordFactory.java:167)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.TrainLogistic.main(TrainLogistic.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:187)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:186)
```

What am i doing wrong?

How do you debug this.. what is the error??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is your input doesn't exist or is empty. I'd check that `/path/mahout_input/complete/input.csv` is really what you mean.

Comment: It is there.. I checked it again

Comment: The field separators in your input file are different than what mahout CSV reader expects. So I guess it is not able split and find predictors from first line.

Answer (score 3):

Either check your input path or make sure your first line of input path having values in "" only like "x1","x2","x3","lablel"..so on

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well.

My fault was to bypass an incorrect --target parameter, which does not exists in columns. Specifically my header line was

```
myColumn1,myColumn2,myColumn3
```

and my command line was

mahout trainlogistic --input ./input.csv --output ./logistic_model
**--target myMisTypedColumn1** --predictors myColumn2 myColumn3 --types w w w --features 2 --passes 100 --rate 50 --categories 2

One another tip is: Dont use " ( quotes) or long column names, so you should avoid the headache of "Does mahout did not like my column name?" etc.

And as a feedback to MAHOUT: the error message is terrible. We should never see a "NullPointerException" in such a promising framework.